# Meaning of 初デートの記念というやつです

Tags: meaning

To provide context, the two people were out on a date, and one offered to buy the other a bracelet, and she responded with.

> 「ではありがたくいただきましょうか。初{はつ}デートの記念{きねん}**というやつ**です」

I can sort of understand that she is saying that this bracelet will act as something to 'celebrate' their first date, however, what exactly *というやつ* is doing is not clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

> 「ではありがたくいただきましょうか。初{はつ}デートの記念{きねん}というやつです。」

≒

> 「ではありがたくいただきましょうか。『初デートの記念』というやつです。」

「～～という**やつ**」 is a colloquial way of saying "***what one might call ~~***".

「やつ」 here means "a/the thing", not a "person".

> "I will take it with gratitude, then.  It is what I might call a commemoration of our first date."